# Function range() in Python language does not give the expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

As a beginner in python, I was trying to test the function range() in the IDLE terminal.
I wrote in the terminal the below posted code and I expected to see result like this:

```
range(10)==>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But unfortunately, i do not get the expected result

Python Code I Tried:

```
range(10)
print(range(10))
```

The Result From The shell:

```
range(10)
```

Comment: You haven't assigned the `range(10)` to a variable in the first line. The second line `print(range(10))` should work.

Comment: `range(11)`? `range(1, 11)`?

Comment: Are you using python 3.x?

Comment: If you are using python3 `range` is now what `xrange` was in python2. To obtain a `list` of numbers use `list(range(...))`.

Comment: @Ashwini: i'm using python 3.3.1

Comment: @limelights: i have already tried print(range(10)), but it did not work

Comment: @Bakuriu:I have python 3.3.1 and using the function range() alone does not work..but now I have tried what did you suggest, which is list(range(10)), and it worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In python 3, `range()` returns a generator, that's why it shows you the object rather than the values:

```
>>> print(range(10))
range(0, 10)
```

If you were expecting a list, you will need to convert it to one before printing it:

```
>>> print(list(range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Generators only create one value at a time in order to save memory. You can read up on them [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which includes an example suited to your test case.

Comment: Eh, same conclusion i came to.

Answer (score 1):

## Cross version solution

```
C:\Documents and Settings\U009071\Desktop>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> print(list(range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>>
```

## Python2:

```
>>> print(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a = range(10)
>>> print(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Don't know your Python version, but mine works fine.
Try specifying `range(0,10)` to be sure.

Comment: `range(0, 10)` is equivalent to `range(10)` for any version of Python (well at least from v2.0 on and if you are using pre-2001 Python...)

Comment: I'm away, i'm also aware that he described a issue that shouldn't occur.. so any option that can be thrown in there to solve the mystery error is valid to note :)

Comment: @glglgl good point, `list` is just a type defenition per se so it should work just as fine in Python2 as in Python3.

Comment: @Torxed - no, list is a little more than a type definition, it is actually a constructor that takes an enumerable, and that behavior is consistent between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire and everything is a object, i'm well aware. I shouldn't begin to argue specifics with anyone of you because i tend to "ease up" on the language unless i got a few hours do dig in to a subject or i get paied to do so, my free time is limited and i just mentioned that the the baseline is that list() returns a list definition and not some other variable, and since a list is iterable i made the assumption that a non-monkey would figure the other stuff out, i just pointed the lad in a general direction.
Also, answer marked as solved, i stoped caring about specifics :)